# How to make problems tab show build warnings when building via ssh

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

On my linux VM I have set up a docker container to build and debug my vs code C++ project via an ssh connection. Building works inside the container as well as running and debugging with breakpoints. I am stuck on how to redirect stdout to the Output and Problems tabs so i can see warnings generated from the build and then navigate to the affected files. Instead it just outputs the build to a terminal window.

The project is located in a docker volume in the location:

> /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/vol-tom-2/_data/My-Project

And inside the container it is located in:

> /home/buildmaster/workspace/My-Project

For debugging i have modified the launch.json file so that when setting breakpoints it matches up the files in the project to the ones in the container, by adding this line:

```
 "sourceFileMap": {
                "/home/user/workspace": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/vol-tom-2/_data/"
            },
```

I would like to find something similar in tasks.json so that it can sync up my local vs code project with the warnings and errors generated from the build inside the container.

Below is my tasks.json file, thanks in advance if any one has any idea how to solve this!

```
    {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "command": "/bin/sh",
    "args": ["-c"],
    "reveal": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
             "args": [
                "user@localhost",
                "-p",
                "32772",
                "/home/build-scripts/build-script.sh"
            ],
            "label": "build",
            "command": "ssh",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^\/host\/(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            },          
        }
    ]
}
```